# i dont know why but every line in my code is displayed as a error

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new in using eclipse , i dont understand why everything is being shown as a error, I also have turned off all the firewalls and security my pc has but no luck yet

[image]

Comment: rebuild your project

Comment: do one thing clean the prject and build it again from "Prjoect "  menu.

Comment: Hover on the first import underlined, and see what Eclipse says, most likely it will give you a fix option.

Comment: Eclipse does that sometimes. In most cases cleaning and rebuilding should help. If it doesn't try to start Eclipse with the ` -clean` option.

Comment: @zoubida13 Those are all JDK imports and eclipse _should_ not have any problems importing those - it still sometimes messes up though.

Comment: I have done that too but this is happening to every program every time even a Hello world Android program is also not getting executed

Comment: @Thomas it would give you a hint about something that went wrong with the imports, such as typos....

Comment: @zoubida13 not always, I sometimes have a similar situation where Eclipse can't find classes in the same package (lying directly next to the class that should use them) or Eclipse complaining about not being able to find `java.lang` etc.

Answer (score 5):

You've got typos in your imports:

- java.awt.event.ActionListner -> java.awt.event.ActionListener
- javax.Swing.JFrame -> java.swing.JFrame
- javax.Swing.JTextField -> java.swing.JTextField
- javax.Swing.JPasswordField -> javax.swing.JPasswordField
- javax.Swing.OptionPane -> javax.swing.OptionPane

Delete the imports that have the red lines under them and hit Ctrl+Shift+O. That will clean them up automatically.

Comment: Or `<Ctl><Shift><i>` in Netbeans.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon the user stated that this was eclipse in the tags, not netbeans

Comment: Good spot, as someone who uses `<Ctrl><Shift><O>` unconsciously but still having problems with Eclipse at times I just assumed the imports had been written correctly (i.e. automagically). :)

Answer (score 0):

it says tat the classes from

```
javax.swing
```

cannot be imported, so the possibilites are:

clean project,
rebuild project,
check build path,
check if libraries are present(maybe could be deleted for error)

Answer (score 0):

You may have missed jdk lib / requried jars .
In eclipse rgt click project folder - > build path - > configure Build Path -> On rigt side under libraries / jars tab -> Add JARS,Add Library. 
Hope it gives you some hint.